# Using Static Nested Class in JSP Tag

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am having trouble referencing a static inner class in a JSP tag file. I am using Glassfish Jersey and Jetty 6.1.X. I am using JSP 2.0 and tagfiles, and I don't have any TagHandler classes or any .tld files. My web.xml also doesn't contain anything specific about JSPs or tag files.

I have broken down the problem into the smallest reproducible:

This is the structure of the class I am using:

```
package test;

public class OuterClass {

    public static class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

This is the complete contents of my .tag file:

```
<%@ attribute name="inner" required="true" type="test.OuterClass.InnerClass" %>
<h1>${inner}</h1>
```

(The tag file shows an error in IntelliJ):

[image: IntelliJ Error]

I use this tag in my parent jsp like so:

```
<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="test" %>
<test:test inner="${inner}"/>
```

The exception that I get when attempting to use it this way is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp(54,4) 
Unknown attribute type (test.OuterClass.InnerClass) for attribute inner
```

If I change the type to use the binary notation (OuterClass$InnerClass) I get this error instead:

```
The nested type test.OuterClass$InnerClass cannot be referenced using its binary name
```

I have searched Google for this and found others with the same problem, but all of these seem to have been resolved by a fix to Jasper years ago.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41824
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35351

I have bypassed the problem by splitting the class into many top level classes instead, but the nested classes in my use case necessarily belong to the top level class, and shouldn't be used outside of this so it feels wrong to change the design due to the limitation I am finding here.

If there is a way to properly used static nested classes in a tag attribute, then that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Did you try `<%@page import="test.OuterClass"%>` and / or `<%@page import="test.OuterClass.InnerClass"%>` ?

Comment: Yep, tried both of them and still get the same error in the server. Strangely enough I don't get any errors if I import the class and do ```
<% OuterClass.InnerClass inner = new OuterClass.InnerClass(); %>``` in the tag file, it's only when passed as an attribute that there's a problem.

Comment: Strangely, you can use a static inner class if you convert it into an enum. *IntelliJ IDEA* still reports an error, but the code works in *Tomcat* 6.0+.